# Why colors change when I export from Illustrator to Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, color, export, color-spaces

I am working on a Illustrator file that I need to export to Photoshop to edit.

When I'm exporting it changes the color of my black and it becomes quite dull. The same thing happens when I export it as a PNG from the Photoshop file.

I know my Photoshop file is in CMYK and I am wondering how to have the black output like it was in Illustrator, or is it normal to see it this way? 
I am not used to work with those programs so sorry in advance if I can't understand your answer.

Comment: Hi Emilie, Welcome to Graphic Design Stack Exchange. First, ensure your settings are compatible in both Photoshop and Illustrator by closing both, open Bridge and make all your settings in Bridge so Bridge can then make the correct setting in both Ps and AI. That's why it's called Bridge and that's what it's for.

Comment: PNGs don't support CMYK colour.  Try exporting as a CMYK TIFF from Illustrator instead.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like your issue is coming from your settings for viewing/exporting blacks.

In the image below you can see the difference between backs. A black with the `CMYK` values of *0-0-0-100* is known as **registration black**. And a black with the `CMYK` values of *100-100-100-100* is known as **4-color black**.
[image]

Your issue sounds like you have the top setting as display all blacks as Rich Black but the Printing/Exporting setting as Output all Blacks Accurately.

Check your settings and adjust them according to what you want to see. If you want the darker or "less dull" black, make sure that your settings are:

> Display All Blacks as Rich Black

and

> Output All Blacks as Rich Black

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not entirely correct. Actually CMYK(0, 0, 0, 100) is just called "Black". CMYK(100, 100, 100, 100) is called "Registration" and is only used for trim marks and other marks when printing. It should never be used for design. "Rich Black" is what you get when you convert RGB(0, 0, 0) to CMYK. The "Appearance of Black" setting should not be adjusted according to what you like to see. In my opinion it should always be set to "Accurately" so nothing is obscured.

Answer (score -1):

You may synchronize color settings across Adobe applications

[Here is solution from Adobe itself](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/creativesuite/cs/using/WS37C6D4EA-9407-4954-9A03-92735E070188.html#WSA0A53A1F-BF46-4624-82C6-340A70EFB8C4)

> 1. Open Bridge. To open Bridge from a Creative Suite application,
>      choose <kbd>File > Browse</kbd>. To open Bridge directly, either choose Adobe
>      Bridge from the Start menu (Windows) or double-click the Adobe
>      Bridge icon (Mac OS).
> 2. Choose <kbd>Edit > Creative SuiteColor Settings</kbd>.
> 3. Select a color setting from the list, and click <kbd>Apply</kbd>.
> 4. If none of the default settings meet your requirements, select <kbd>Show Expanded List Of Color Setting Files</kbd> to view additional settings.
>      To install a custom settings file, such as a file you received from a
>      print service provider, click <kbd>Show Saved Color Settings Files</kbd>.